# Why it draws slow? or strange?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view

I'm trying to do a view that allows the user to "draw" on it. Right now what I do are paths and then I connect it with a line, but don't work properly, it work slow and make things "strange". You can see that on this video http://youtu.be/PUSUTFhDPrM , sorry, it goes a bit fast, but you can see what I'm talking about.

My actual code is:

```
public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener {

private static final String TAG = "DrawView";

private List<List<Point>> _paths = new ArrayList<List<Point>>();
private List<Point> _lastPath;
private Paint _paint = new Paint();
private Path _path = new Path();

public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    setOnTouchListener(this);

    _paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    _paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    _paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    _paint.setAntiAlias(true);
}
public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super( context, attrs );

    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    setOnTouchListener(this);

    _paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    _paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    _paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    _paint.setAntiAlias(true);
}

public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super( context, attrs, defStyle );

    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    setOnTouchListener(this);

    _paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    _paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    _paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    _paint.setAntiAlias(true);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    for (List<Point> pointsPath : _paths) {
        _path.reset();
        boolean first = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < pointsPath.size(); i += 2) {
            Point point = pointsPath.get(i);

            if (first) {
                first = false;
                _path.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
            } else if (i < pointsPath.size() - 1) {
                Point next = pointsPath.get(i + 1);
                _path.quadTo(point.x, point.y, next.x, next.y);
            } else {
                _path.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
            }
        }
        canvas.drawPath(_path, _paint);
    }
}

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    Point point = new Point();
    point.x = event.getX();
    point.y = event.getY();
    Log.d(TAG, "point: " + point);

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        _lastPath = new ArrayList<Point>();
        _lastPath.add(point);
        _paths.add(_lastPath);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        _lastPath.add(point);
        break;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

private class Point {
    float x, y;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return x + ", " + y;
    }
}
public void changePaint(int Stroke, int color){

    _path.reset();

    _paint.setColor(color);
    _paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    _paint.setStrokeWidth(Stroke);
    _paint.setAntiAlias(true);

}

}
```

What I want is know if there is a better method to allow the user to "draw " with the finger or what can I improve to remove the slowest part of this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your draw operation is fine. The worse thing to do when drawing is instanciating new objects and you don't do it.

To comment @Atermis's answer, actually it doesn't make much sense to "draw in the background". Drawing in Android happens on the UI Thread, if you had heavy computations to draw, then yes, it could be useful, but here something simpler could be the solution : a double buffer.

Either you could use a surface view and [lockCanvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#lockCanvas%28%29) or you could draw in a memory buffer and then display it in a single operation as explained here : http://www.mail-archive.com/android-beginners@googlegroups.com/msg03172.html.

Comment: If I implement lockCanvas, my line will be drawed at the same time that the finge touches the screen?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the problem is that you perform such action on UI thread, try to do it on background thread.

Comment: Take a look at this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z2YogvILjvo And this is a good example of drawing something on canvas http://android-journey.blogspot.co.il/2010/02/android-2d-simple-example.html

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read about batching of the `MotionEvent` here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html

Basically you can get a list of all coordinates between current and last X,Y by using `getHistoricalX` and `getHistoricalY`.